# Selenium Python pick first child element

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, web-scraping

I have the following problem. I am trying to scrape some prices of a website using Python. However, whenever I check the css_selector or xpath of the first search result the code keeps changing numbers.

When I make a search query the css_selector for the first result may look like this.

`div.serp_block:nth-child(28) > div:nth-child(1) > ... > b:nth-child(1)`

Using xpath it slightly changes between searches.

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[3]/div[1]/div/a/b
/html/body/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[3]/div[1]/div/a/b
```

How can I determine the css or xpath of the first child element for each search? The content of the search result increases in increments of 1 and I know how many search results I get. So I only need to know how I can reliably select it. If there is a better/different approach for selecting child elements then I would excited to hear about it as well.

Comment: There are plenty xpath tutorials around the web. Those kind of xpaths you are trying to use are useless, you should use patterns like `//form[@id="whatever"]//div[class="item"]//span[@data-pricetag]`

Comment: Your question is not clear me to. Can you share some HTML and reframe your question ?

Answer (score 0):

You can give an index of the whole XPath

```
(/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[3]/div[1]/div/a/b)[1]
(/html/body/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[3]/div[1]/div/a/b)[1]
```

You have to pass the index as per which element you want to locate.